# Typesafe SBT - update from Play 2.0.2 to Play 2.0.3

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm using Typesafe's sbt tool of version 0.11.3 and it has Play Framework of 2.0.2 embedded. However, 2.0.3 has already been released and it has a bugfix I'd like to get.

Is there some command to run from sbt tool and update all tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change version of play in project/plugins.sbt file.

Addendum: sbt does not embed play, play is just a library, which is added to your project as a plugin. Plugins are usually defined in project/plugins.sbt file, so you just need to modify it with appropriate version and reload the project.

Answer (score 1):

You need download the latest version of Play. Then update the plugins.sbt file in your project and run 'play update'.